# libgit2: Convert remote branch ref to valid refspec

Tags: git, libgit2

I want to push to some remote branch that has a different name as my local branch. Lets say local is `refs/heads/master` and remote is `refs/remotes/origin/foo`

Now a valid refspec would be `refs/heads/master:refs/heads/foo`

How to I convert the remote branch name to `refs/heads/foo` so that `git_remote_push` will correctly push?

I'm currently using naive string ops by stripping the remote name from the remote branch `shorthand` and prepending `refs/heads/`, but this seems a bit to fagile for me. Is there no API for that?

Comment: Any better solutions?